# How to organize Rmarkdown files (with Shiny runtime) inside a package

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-package, flexdashboard

Currently I have an analysis project which I treated as package.
So currently I have the following structure:

```
mycoolanalysispackage/
|-- .Rbuildignore
|-- .gitignore
|-- DESCRIPTION
|-- NAMESPACE
|-- inst
|-- vignettes
|-- R
`-- mycoolanalysispackage.Rproj
```

At the end I usually produce many Shiny applications as  [Rmarkdown-flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html) file with Shiny runtime.

```
  -- app1/
       |-- index.Rmd
  -- app2/
       |-- index.Rmd
```

My question is, in which package subdirectory should I put those application directories (along with their `index.Rmd` files)?

I also have local [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/), what's the best way to link that Rmarkdown-flexdashboard app to that server?

Answer (score 1):

As with everything else, you place them in a subfolder of the `inst` folder when developing the package. When the package is installed, all folders in the `inst` folder will be moved to the package folder, and hence can be used as subfolders. So

```
mycoolanalysispackage/
|-- .Rbuildignore
|-- .gitignore
|-- DESCRIPTION
|-- NAMESPACE
|-- inst
     |-- app1/
       |-- index.Rmd
     |-- etc...
|-- R
`-- mycoolanalysispackage.Rproj
```

To access the files from within an R function, you can use `system.file`:

```
system.file("app1","index.Rmd",package = "mycoolanalysispackage")
```

will give you the exact path to the index.Rmd of app1. That result can then be used to deploy the app using the appropriate functions.

See also the manual [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) (scroll down a bit)

Comment: Thanks a lot. In order for `system.file()`command  and R chunk inside `app1/index.Rmd`  to work, do we first have to install the package locally like this `devtools::install_local("mycoolanalysispackage")` ?

Comment: @pdubois obviously, otherwise it can't find the installation directory of the package. I typically build the package using `R CMD`, install it and test it. That's still the safest route, especially when you also want to check your vignettes.

Comment: Thanks again. And can you give example for this `That result can then be used to deploy the app using the appropriate functions.`? I'm a heavy user of RStudio.